# Laravel withSum where clause column not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 9 to perform a `withSum` on my relationship `credit_transactions`. I need to return all `PersonalAccessToken` models where the `credit_balance` is less than a certain value, for example, 50 - this way my application knows whether to top up their balance.

This is my query:

```php
/**
 * Get all keys that can be auto topped-up
 */
public function getEnabledTopUpKeys()
{
    return PersonalAccessToken::whereNotNull('region_code')
                              ->where('auto_topup_enabled', true)
                              ->whereNotNull('auto_topup_slug')
                              ->withSum('credit_transactions AS credit_balance', 'delta')
                              ->where('credit_balance', '<', 100)
                              ->get();
}
```

This doesn't work, it throws an error:

> Unknown column 'credit_balance' in 'where clause'

What am I missing to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

`withSum` generates a sub query, so it can't be used in a `where` query. But that sub query creates an on-the-fly column that you can add to your query. For instance,

```
Order::withSum('orderItems', 'quantity')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

creates an aliased column named `order_items_sum_quantity`, that I can then use as a `having` query:

```
Order::withSum('orderItems', 'quantity')
    ->having('order_items_sum_quantity', '>', 100)
    ->take(5)->get();
```

In your case, you may be getting a column named `credit_balance_sum_delta` that you can use in your query:

```
PersonalAccessToken::whereNotNull('region_code')
    ->where('auto_topup_enabled', true)
    ->whereNotNull('auto_topup_slug')
    ->withSum('credit_transactions AS credit_balance', 'delta')
    ->having('credit_balance_sum_delta', '<', 100)
    ->get();
```

If that isn't quite the correct column name, try getting one record without the `having` line, then check the results to find out the column name